# How can I fix this error? Error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, module

I have two pages:

**blockchain.js:**

```
 function Blockchain() {
        this.chain = [] ;
        this.newTransactions = [] ;
    }
Blockchain.prototype.createNewBlock = function (nonce,previousHash,hash) {
    const newBlock = {
        tranactions : this.newTransactions,
        nonce : nonce ,
        hash : hash ,
        previousHash : previousHash
    };
    this.newTransactions = [] ;
    this.chain.push(newBlock);

    return newBlock ;
}
module.exports = Blockchain;
```

**test.js:**

```
const Blockchain = require('./blockchain') ;
const bitcoin = new Blockchain() ;

bitcoin.createNewBlock(23833,'asjakdja' , 'asdasdasdadasd') ;
console.log(bitcoin);
```

When I use `node test.js`, it produces the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'E:\wamp\www\blockchain\test'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:453:25)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
  at startup (bootstrap_node.js:201:16)
  at bootstrap_node.js:626:3
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: try this `const { Blockchain } = require('./blockchain') ;`

Comment: or this `new Blockchain.Blockchain()`

Comment: what version of js must be used ??

Comment: I am working on webstorme IDE

Comment: @mosi Are those file in the same folder? It works for me.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn they are exporting the function directly, not an object with a `Blockchain` property.

Comment: @mosi can you expand on "don't work", are you getting an error?

Comment: yes , two file in one folder

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'E:\wamp\www\blockchain\test'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:453:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:201:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:626:3

Comment: That's telling you it can't even find `test.js`. Are you running `node test.js` from the same directory that `test.js` is in?

Comment: @Mark Meyer , yes I use `node test` in webstorm terminal

Comment: @mosi I understand that, but just because you are in the webstorm terminal doesn't mean you are in the right directory. Does typing `pwd` show you the correct directory?

Comment: @Mark Meyer  , Excuse me sir , I was in dev folder .. thank you